# Rees algebra is finitely generated if associated graded algebra is

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebras, filtrations, graded-algebras

$
\newcommand{\cn}{\colon}
\newcommand{\<}{\leqslant}
\newcommand{\>}{\geqslant}
\newcommand{\ss}{\subset}
\newcommand{\k}{\mathrm{k}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\mathrm{gr}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathrm{R}}
\newcommand{\ov}{\overline}
\newcommand{\l}{\lambda}
$Let $\k$ be a field, $A$ be associative algebra with unity $1$ over $\k$ and filtration $0=F_{-1}\ss F_0\ss F_1\ss\ldots\ss A=\bigcup_i F_i$, $1\in F_0$, $\gr(A)=\bigoplus_{i\>0} F_i/F_{i-1}$ be associated graded algebra which is finitely generated by homogeneous elements $\ov{a_1},\ldots,\ov{a_n}$ of degrees $d_1,\ldots,d_n$. That is, for all $\ov{f_m}\in F_m/F_{m-1}$ exist $\l_i\in\k,~k_{i,m,j}\in\mathbb N$ such that
\begin{align}
&F_m/F_{m-1}\ni\ov{f_m}=\sum_{(i,m)} \l_{i,m}\ov{a_{i_{m,1}}^{k_{i,m,1}}\ldots 
a_{i_{m,n}}^{k_{i,m,n}}}\in\bigoplus_{i\>0} F_i/F_{i-1}
\\
\rightsquigarrow~&\forall i,m\cn\ov{a_{i_{m,1}}^{k_{i,m,1}}\ldots 
a_{i_{m,n}}^{k_{i,m,n}}}\in F_m/F_{m-1}
\\
\rightsquigarrow~&\forall i,m\cn (\ov{a_{i_{m,1}}^{k_{i,m,1}}\ldots 
a_{i_{m,n}}^{k_{i,m,n}}}\ne \ov 0\rightsquigarrow k_{i,m,1}d_{i_{m,1}}+\ldots +k_{i,m,n}d_{i_{m,n}}=m).\tag{1}
\end{align}

**Def.** *Rees algebra* $\R(A)$ is a subalgebra $\sum_{m\>0}F_m t^m$ of $A[t]$.

I want to prove that $\R(A)$ is finitely generated by $t,a_1t^{d_1},\ldots,a_nt^{d_n}$, where $a_i$ is a preimage of $\ov{a_i}$ (exercise 5-(ii) after chapter 1 from **Kassel's Quantum Groups**).

Let $\sum f_mt^m\in \R(A)$. Therefore
\begin{align}
&\sum_m f_mt^m=f_0(a_1t^{d_1})^0+\sum_{m>0}\sum_{(i,m)}\l_{i,m}a_{i_{m,1}}^{k_{i,m,1}}\ldots 
a_{i_{m,n}}^{k_{i,m,n}}t^m.
\end{align}
Assume that $\ov{e=a_{i_{m,1}}^{k_{i,m,1}}\ldots 
a_{i_{m,n}}^{k_{i,m,n}}}=\ov 0\in\gr(A)$. Then $ e\in\cap_{i\>0}F_i=F_0$ and $m=\deg e=0$. As a consequence, from $(1)$ we get
$$
\sum_m f_mt^m=f_0(a_1t^{d_1})^0+\sum_{m>0}\sum_{(i,m)}\l_{i,m}(a_{i_{m,1}}t^{d_{i_{m,1}}})^{k_{i,m,1}}\ldots 
(a_{i_{m,n}}t^{d_{i_{m,n}}})^{k_{i,m,n}}.
$$
So $\R(A)$ is generated by $\{a_it^{d_i}\}_{i=1}^n$.

Is it correct?

Comment: It's not Ree but Rees.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez fixed